# Deallocation of NSMutableArray inside a Function

Tags: objective-c, memory, memory-management, nsmutablearray

Here is my code:

```
- (void)showRectangles
{
  NSMutableArray *rects = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
  //....rest of code here
  [rects release];
}
```

The problem here is that when I analyze the code, it gives me this warning:

`Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller`

I don't understand why this gives me a warning. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Something in "rest of code" has either re-assigned or already released `rects`; by themselves these two lines are perfectly correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by expanding the message in the problem navigator, xcode will point out every ref count op for you. ultimately, this will show you how the static analyzer came to this conclusion.

alternatively, it's possible you have reassigned the variable `rects` along the way (introducing a leak and over-release).